is it possible to express the threshold energy in photoelectric effect in terms of ionisation energy + something
I was studying the variation of stopping potential with frequency of incident light and wanted to compare this graph for different metals. It's clear to me that if it's easy to unbound an electron from its atom, more energy will be imparted to it in the form of kinetic energy, thus that electron would require a higher stopping potential.
The first thing that came to mind for comparison was naturally the ease with which an electron can be ejected from the valence shell that is the ionisation energy. So I was certain if I compared the threshold energy for Na and K, K would have a lower threshold energy than Na since it's easier to eject an electron. That wasn't the case apparently.
Then I realised that we were talking about an isolated gaseous atom in case of ionisation energy and we were dealing with solid atoms in bulk here. That leads to my question what energy would be required in addition to ionisation energy to eject an electron in photoelectric effect.
My first guess would be this relation,
threshold energy = atomisation or sublimation energy + ionisation energy
but I cant be sure.
I'm still in grade 12 and the moment I think of what may have happened on the atomic scale its a waste of time. Too many plotholes in the physics i've read so far everything is a property, i cant even begin to imagine what exactly a charge is, its cause and its effect on an electron. That aside I'd like to stick with classical mechanics since its easier no imagination just theory.

Consider that atoms at the surface of a substance behave differently from those inside -- there are asymmetrical forces on those atoms.  This involves surface plasmons, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_plasmon,  which complicate ionization.
